Git: return to last version after returning to an old version for testing
I'm developing a program and use Git to save versions of it, using git commit.
I wanted to test an old version of my program, so I went back to this version using git checkout id-of-the-commit. I modified a file there simply to change the names of the input files to process with this old version of my program.
Now that I get the results I wanted with my old program, I'd like to go back to the last version of my program. So I tried git checkout master. This returns an error:
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    code/launch_program.sh
    code/__pycache__/feature.cpython-310.pyc
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting

I'm very new in Git and have trouble to find an answer to my question mainly because I don't understand all the Git jargon.

"Please commit or stash the changes". If you want to keep the changes you made to the file, you need to commit or stash them. Otherwise undo them (git reset -- <filename>) and then you can go back to the latest version. If you need hep on committing changes, stashing changes, or undoing changes ,then it might help if you research those, attempt them, then ask a specific question if you get stuck.

1. You can ignore (and overwrite) modified files using git checkout -f master; see git help checkout. 2. Generated files like *.pyc should have been ignored from the very beginning and never committed.

@mason Of course I've made research on these things. "Attempting them" while I don't understand them is quite scary.

@phd Thanks, git checkout -f master was what I was looking for.

@TVG If you're unsure of what the commands do after reading the relevant documentation and performing other research, there's nothing that stops you from testing out the effects yourself. Create a new repo, make some commits, go back to a prior commit to recreate the situation you're in, and try things out.

@mason Sounds like a good thing to do indeed. However, in my research I didn't find an answer mentioning git checkout -f master, so I'm not sure I'd have tested the right thing. I hope this kind of question, written without jargon, would help beginners like me. Anyway, thanks for your help!

To be fair, the error message doesn't acknowledge that git checkout -f master is a viable option. (Perhaps it's being overly cautious to avoid people losing changes by accident.)

Keep in mind that a branch, like master, is merely a string pointing to a particular commit. When you said git checkout <the-id>, you did not move the master branch pointer; you are now not on any branch, a state that Git calls "detached head" (and you would have seen this in Git's responses to you).
This is fine, but you can't do any real work (i.e. work that you intend to keep) without being on a branch, so if you are just playing around (experimenting), when you're done, you just want to get back to master. To do that, instead of git checkout master, say:
git reset --hard

That means: "OK, Git, I'm done fooling around here experimenting with the past; throw away my experiments and put me back on master!"
If, on the other hand, you had wanted to keep the results of your experiments and incorporate them into master, then you would add-and-commit them, make a branch to point to them, go back to master, and cherry-pick that commit onto the end of master:
git add .
git commit -m 'a useful experiment'
git branch temp
git switch master
git cherry-pick temp


Is there any difference doing git reset --hard or git checkout -f master?

@TVG I think they would have just the same effect. But I regard git checkout as "retired", replaced by other commands; I haven't used it in years. What I told you is what I actually do when (as quite often happens) I do the same thing you did.
